# Run all the validations for a field in react-hook-form

Tags: validation, error-handling, react-hook-form

I am using react-hook-form in my project. I have multiple validators for a same field in my form. Example: firstName field has two validators, 1. minLength, 2. a pattern validator.

```
        {...register("firstName", {
          minLength: 5,
          pattern: /^[A-Za-z]+$/i
        })}
```

There might be possibility that both validation may fail at same time, and I need to show both errors one below another. But formState.errors object only have one error. So for above example if the value is **123** then it should show both error messages one below another, but it shows minLength error message only.
Here is the code sample - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-apply-validation-forked-377q8f?file=/src/index.js:587-692

Comment: Where have you seen something like that? I don't think is a good design nor is possible. You must place your validation in order from the most possibly to fail to the less possibly cause validation is tested sequentially

Comment: @OsmanysFuentes-Lombá Just because you don't need it doesn't mean it's "bad design." I came across this question just now because I have the exact same use case.

Answer (score 0):

The `criteriaMode` property is what you're looking for. It determines whether to display all validation errors or only one at a time.

According to [documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform#criteriaMode)

> When set to `firstError` (default), only the first error from each field will be gathered.
> When set to `all`, all errors from each field will be gathered.

```js
useForm({
  criteriaMode: 'all',
})
```